# sleep() method behavior in synchronize block

Tags: java, sleep, synchronize

```
class ThreadRunnable implements Runnable{
  synchronized public void run(){       
    System.out.println("In Runnable implemented class");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(60000);
        System.out.println("sleeping over");
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        ThreadRunnable tr = new ThreadRunnable();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(tr);

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadRunnable());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

As its in synchronize method, t2 thread should print the SOP after t1, but both the threads print the SOP simultaneously. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: 'simultaneously'? Anyway there is no guarantee on the order of threads execution.

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to solve your problem. So you please use that "preview" window to check the indenting of your input *prior* posting your question. And just for the record, as that is so often forgotten: dont forget about accepting one of the answers at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `synchronized` method implicitly synchronizes on `this`. In your case the instance of `ThreadRunnable`.

But each thread has its own instance so they use two different monitors.

You have several options to solve your issue such as:

- use a `private static final Object lock = new Object();` as a monitor with a synchronized block.
- or more simply `Thread t2 = new Thread(tr);`

Answer (score 3):

You are creating **two** instances of your class.

`synchronized` prevents that different methods invoke the method on the **same** method in parallel.

It doesn't prevent calling methods in parallel on **different** objects!

Answer (score 1):

There is no mutual exclusion. Both of the objects have their own separate monitors that they acquire at `synchronized`, so they both run at the same time.

If you want to see a difference, pass `tr` to your second thread as well. Then you have 2 threads sharing 1 object (and one lock).